# Compile Dynamic Content as embedded resource in a xap file

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, scorm

I'm writing a silverlight client that will be used as a player in a SCORM export to LMS.

This player will need to access Dynamic Content like images, audio files and video files. (since it is dynamic, we cannot manually compile these as embedded resources). Scorm however does NOT allow remote connections. Which means we will have to push the resources to the client.

Now for the question:
Is there a way to add dynamic content to a xap file at runtime (at the moment we create the SCORM package) ?

If my question is unclear please don't hesitate to tell me so :)

Thnx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the SCORM documentation makes it clear that it doesn't allow remote connections, The CMS doesn't block it. 
So silverlight can still load the external resources ;-)